# Create a branch from specific revision of another branch tortoiseSVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I created a branch from specific revision (For example, revision 10) of source branch using TortoiseSVN.
After creating the branch, the revision number 10 is missing from the source branch.
Please help.

Does branching affect the source copy in any way? How can I make sure that my source branch is unaffected by creation of this new branch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Branching never affects the branch source in any way. There is nothing you can do while branching to in any way affect the branch source.

As far as a revision being missing: nope, it isn't missing.

Every revision in your repository contains every single file and directory on every single branch. If revision 10 exists, and a branch was created prior to revision 10, then there is a revision 10 for that branch.

In your case, there were probably no changes in revision 10 on the source branch. Since there were no changes, there is no reason to show that revision in the log.

In SVN, revisions contain branches (and files and directories), not the other way around. So you can think of it as "branch X as it existed in revision 10" rather than "revision 10 of branch X". The former is always correct. The latter is sometimes a useful simplification but in your situation can cause confusion.

Comment: Thanks that revision didnt have any changes but was created for tagging purposes. I can understand if it doesn't show up in the newly created branch's log; But it was previously showing up in the log of the source  revision. What could be the reason?

Comment: No idea. Maybe something to do with the "show only affected paths" checkbox?